# PayPal 3-day guarantee on Auth/Capture if buyer uses CC

Tags: paypal, authorization, capture

PayPal says that that guarantee funds for 3 days if seller is using Authorization/Capture.  Does this guarantee stand if the buyer chooses to use a Credit Card instead of funds in a PayPal account?

Answer (score 0):

When someone makes an Express Checkout or credit card authorization (though PayPal Payments Pro), that authorization is good for up to 29 days, provided you don't extend it.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/admin/auth-capture/

Comment: I realize that but I don't see how PayPal can guarantee payment if the buyer chooses to use a credit card instead of his PayPal funds.

Comment: That's how authorizations in general work. When I run one, I am guaranteed the funds or I'm not. It's not a done deal until I capture the funds, however.

As far as how it works in Express Checkout, that's PayPal's business. They merely guarantee you the funds.